# SQL 'multiple schemas on same DB' or 'multiple DB' on same server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have an SQL database server with many tables most using the default schema **dbo**.TABLE and specific tables use something like **Library**.TABLE on the same Database, which is kinda of a way for me to know that these tables belong/being used by a Library system/application and the default schema 'dbo' ones contain generic data that can be used in any system that utilize this DB server. one reason it is like this is simple it was given to me like this.

i have a plan to extend this database with more system tables which is somehow related to each other. (for example: 'Librarian time-sheet', 'borrowed books list', etc...) but i am wondering if i should keep using the same **X**.TABLE naming on the same DB or should i start creating more Databases on the same SQL instance?

i did not finding any concrete answer for this but from what i can see from an App developer side it would be easier to check which system use which DB and tables instead of putting all in one. i assume that if i create more DBs i can later (if needed) start moving DBs to difference SQL instance or different servers entirely more easily.

should i go with **X**.TABLE format or create new DB for each App Table Set assuming i have only one server to work with?

EDIT: i am using MySQL actually but i am not familiar what it is called here i inferred the naming from Oracle

*in response to "Prachi Thakkar" Sorry for the confusion. i meant new DB for each "group" of tables related to a system

Comment: MySQL <> SQL Server. The fact that you are talking about Schemas (such as `dbo`) strongly implies that you are using SQL Server, not MySQL. Please update your tags accordingly.

Comment: Joins across multiple databases will become way slower. If you need them, then don't split into multiple databases.

Answer (score 0):

Creating multiple databases for each new table is not a good approach. The optimal solution is having normalized tables for each functionality under one schema & under one database.